# WCF channel stack performance

Tags: c#, performance, wcf

We have a WCF service that is used heavily and which must support high throughput. I have been tasked to recommend changes to improve performance and have observed strange behavior which I will attempt to describe below.

The service itself is simple and operations take anywhere between 15ms and several seconds to complete depending on what activity is being performed. Additionally there is an endpoint behavior in the form of a dispatch message inspector which audits every inbound and outbound message to an Oracle database.

I have put together a simple load test using Visual Studio which invokes the service using a ramped up load profile from 1 thru to 1000 concurrent calls. The fun starts to happen as the service comes under load.

As the load increases we see a steady increase in response time as would be expected. I then enabled WCF trace get detailed timings as to what was happening in the WCF stack itself.

The WCF trace paints a puzzling story. As load increases the time taken to execute the service itself (i.e. the class implementing the service contract) remains fairly constant at a few tens of milliseconds, however the time spent in the message inspector increases dramatically - well into the hundreds of milliseconds thru to three or four seconds.

Initially I thought the increase was due to the database blocking INSERTS into the audit table, however when I placed stopwatch timings around the database call I found it was taking a respectable 15ms-20ms.

There is nothing fancy about the code in the message inspector, in pseudo code the message inspector AFterMessageReceived and BeforeMessageReply methods look like:

> Open pooled Oracle connection
>   Create parameter and command objects and populate with audit information
>   Execute Non Query (to insert data)
>   Close connection

I Cannot figure out why the audit behavior elapsed time as measured in the WCF trace is many times longer than the time measured using the stopwatch timing ... any advice would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour when audit is disabled?

Comment: We disable auditing by removing the behavior from the configuration file. When we do this we see elapsed time in the service itself increasing but not as aggressively as we see in the auditing behavior. The service may go from say taking 15ms up to 500ms but nothing more drastic than that.